# Access XAML Control through C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have got some `TextBlocks` with `x:Name`, i'm able to access this control easily with C#. However I have also got some `DoubleAnimations` with an `x:Name` but unable to access these, why is this?

I have tried this but it does not work, I get an error saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`:

```
//Add completed methods
            DoubleAnimation da1 = (DoubleAnimation)Resources["storyboardLoad"];
            da1.Completed += DoubleAnimationCompleted;
```

**Notifications.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="PhotoManagement.Views.Notification"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhotoManagement.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="NotificationWindow" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" Width="350" SizeToContent="Height">
    <Window.Resources>
        <FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesome">/Fonts/#FontAwesome</FontFamily>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="colour1" Color="#29a1d5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="colour2" Color="#248eb8"/>

        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="NotificationIcon" TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource colour2}" />
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15" />
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="NotificationText" TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource colour1}" />
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="NotificationContainer" TargetType="Grid">
            <!-- Animation -->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryboardLoad">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                             From="0.0"
                                             To="1.0"
                                             Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation x:Name="storyboardLoad" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                             From="1.0" 
                                             To="0.0" 
                                             Duration="0:0:1" 
                                             BeginTime="0:0:2" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>

                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardLoad"/>
                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardFade"/>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>

                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryboardFade">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation x:Name="storyboardFade" 
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                             From="1.0" 
                                             To="0.0" 
                                             Duration="0:0:1" 
                                             BeginTime="0:0:2" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource NotificationContainer}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border Grid.Column="1"
                    CornerRadius="0 5 5 0"
                    Style="{StaticResource NotificationText}">
                <TextBlock Text="A request has been added!" 
                           x:Name="NotificationText"/>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="0" 
                    CornerRadius="5 0 0 5"
                    Style="{StaticResource NotificationIcon}">
                <TextBlock Text=""
                           x:Name="NotificationIcon"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Notifications.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace PhotoManagement.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Notification.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Notification : Window
    {
        public Notification() : base()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Move other windows down when closed
            this.Closed += this.NotificationWindowClosed;

            //Get object properties
            this.NotificationText.Text = "Hello";
            this.NotificationIcon.Text = "G";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Show the Notification and setup it's content and actions
        /// </summary>
        public new void Show()
        {
            this.Topmost = true;
            this.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
            this.Closed += this.NotificationWindowClosed;
            base.Show();

            //Add completed methods


            //Position the Notification
            var workingArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;
            this.Left = (workingArea.Width - this.ActualWidth) / 2;
            double top = workingArea.Bottom - this.ActualHeight - 5;

            //Ensure new notifications are placed above older ones
            foreach (Window window in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
            {
                string windowName = window.GetType().Name;

                if (windowName.Equals("Notification") && window != this)
                {
                    window.Topmost = true;
                    top = window.Top - window.ActualHeight - 5;
                }
            }

            this.Top = top;
        }
        private void ImageMouseUp(object sender,
        System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Close window once animation is complete
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public void DoubleAnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsMouseOver)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Move the next notification down once notification has closed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void NotificationWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Window window in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
            {
                string windowName = window.GetType().Name;

                if (windowName.Equals("NotificationWindow") && window != this)
                {
                    // Adjust any windows that were above this one to drop down
                    if (window.Top < this.Top)
                    {
                        window.Top = window.Top + this.ActualHeight;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the double animations are inside of styles stored as resources.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, I thought this might make it different, but I tried something like `Resources.storyboardLoad` and this doesn't work.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper See updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a custom `Window` or `UserControl`, a (partial) class is generated for it that contains fields for any named child elements. That won't work for styles and templates however - likely because those can be applied to multiple controls, so a name doesn't necessarily map to a single item (or to an item at all).

**The hard way**

So the animation you're looking for is part of a style, which is a resource in your window. To be precise: your style has a collection of triggers. Its first trigger has a 'begin storyboard' action, and that action holds the storyboard you're interested in. It's going to take some searching and type-casting to get there:

```
Style style = (Style)Resources["NotificationContainer"];
EventTrigger trigger = (EventTrigger)style.Triggers[0];
BeginStoryboard beginStoryboard = (BeginStoryboard)trigger.Actions[0];
Storyboard storyboard = beginStoryboard.Storyboard;
```

As you can see, that's quite brittle. All you need to do to break it is reordering the event triggers in XAML...

**The easy way**

But why look up that storyboard anyway? Just bind its `Completed` event to an event handler in XAML directly:

```
<Storyboard Completed="WindowLoadedStoryboard_Completed">
    ...
</Storyboard>
```

Sadly, that's not going to work directly due to a `"The event 'Completed' cannot be specified on a Target tag in a Style. Use an EventSetter instead."` error. And an `EventSetter` is not going to work because `Storyboard.Completed` is not a routed event...

Fortunately, you can work around that by making the storyboard itself a resource, and referencing it in the begin-storyboard action:

```
<Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="WindowLoadedStoryboard" Completed="WindowLoadedStoryboard_Completed">
        ...
    </Storyboard>

    <Style ...>
        ...
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource WindowLoadedStoryboard}" />
        ...
    </Style>
</Resources>
```

Which, incidentally, would also make looking up that storyboard easier and more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, that has helped me to understand the issue more! I have fixed this before reading that, I simply moved the `EventTrigger`'s to the Window.Resources which then allowed me to use the `Completed` tag. So I basically did as you explained, but allowed the triggers to affect the Window instead of the grid, which works the same! Thanks :D